# How to do Multi select option using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I like do multiple select option using PHP , but i am unable to do multiple select.

```
<div class="col-md-6">           
        <label>Department</label>
            <div >
            <?php                                                     
            $options["1"] =  'Production';
            $options["2"] =  'Quality';
            $options["3"] =  'Admin';                               
            echo form_dropdown('distriList',$options,set_value('distriList'), 'id="distriList"'  ,'class="form-control required"','required="true"','multiple ="multiple"');  
            ?>                       
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using a framework? If yes, what framework? If no, what does the function of `form_dropdown()` look like?

Comment: Are you using codeigniter??

Comment: Add `codeigniter` tag in question if its related to this framework to make it more clear.

Comment: I am using codeigniter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `form_multiselect` instead of `from_dropdown`

```
form_multiselect([$name = ''[, $options = array()[, $selected = array()[, $extra = '']]]])
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_multiselect

Answer (score 1):

```
$options = array(
           '1'  => 'Production',
           '2'  => 'Quality',
           '3'  => 'Admin',
            );
$array = array('','');
echo form_multiselect('distriList',$options,$array);
```